# ZSH & Python: python as shell environment variable?

Tags: python, zsh, zshrc

I've been researching setting up ZSH. I've wiped my machine (Mac OS X), installed XCode (Python), ran chsh -s zsh, and installed oh-my-zsh.

The masses seem to rave about Steve Losh's "Prose" theme and his tutorial he wrote in making it. I've been able to incorporate everything relevant to me in it, except for the Battery Info piece. Here's the code:

"I’ve put this script in a file named `batcharge.py` in my `~/bin/` directory. You can of course name it and place it anything/anywhere you like."

> batcharge.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=UTF-8

import math, subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["ioreg", "-rc", "AppleSmartBattery"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]

o_max = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'MaxCapacity' in l][0]
o_cur = [l for l in output.splitlines() if 'CurrentCapacity' in l][0]

b_max = float(o_max.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())
b_cur = float(o_cur.rpartition('=')[-1].strip())

charge = b_cur / b_max
charge_threshold = int(math.ceil(10 * charge))

# Output

total_slots, slots = 10, []
filled = int(math.ceil(charge_threshold * (total_slots / 10.0))) * u'▸'
empty = (total_slots - len(filled)) * u'▹'

out = (filled + empty).encode('utf-8')
import sys

color_green = '%{[32m%}'
color_yellow = '%{[1;33m%}'
color_red = '%{[31m%}'
color_reset = '%{[00m%}'
color_out = (
    color_green if len(filled) > 6
    else color_yellow if len(filled) > 4
    else color_red
)

out = color_out + out + color_reset
sys.stdout.write(out)
```

> .zshrc

```
function battery_charge {
    echo `$BAT_CHARGE` 2>/dev/null
}
```

later in `.zshrc`

```
RPROMPT='$(battery_charge)'
```

I've done exactly this but the battery icon does not appear in Terminal / iTerm. The gaps in my understanding lie in the `$BAT_CHARGE` call and in the `~/bin/` placement. Steve specifies "You can of course name it and place it anything/anwhere you like..." If so, how does your shell know what value to assign $BAT_CHARGE if you place the python file in some random location?

Thanks for any advice,

JW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because earlier in the file you're supposed to assign the location of the script to the environment variable (or omit the environment variable altogether and use the script location directly).

Comment: Could you expound on that? Is this taken care of with the #!/usr/bin/env Python line? How would I go about using the script location directly (I assume this is in reference to the .zshrc file)?

Comment: No, you have to do it yourself. `BAT_CHARGE=~/bin/batcharge.py` or `echo `~/bin/batcharge.py` 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks! I added `BAT_CHARGE=~/.zshfuncs/batcharge.py` to the .zsh-theme, then `chmod 755 batcharge.py` and all worked wonderfully. Appreciate your prompt reply!

Comment: I try to this too, but I cannot get it to parse the color formatting part of the string. It simply writes "[32m-⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡[00m" instead of writing "-⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡" in green. Using slightly modified function, but same output format of the python script, and calling it in the exact same way in my zsh theme file.

Comment: @Thriveth: Are you sure your terminal uses those sequences for colorization?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, but when I use the normal zsh sequences (fg[green] etc.) which normally work, the same thing happens. I see a string with the coloriung sequences stripped of the escape characters like %{ %} etc.

Comment: I can think of a few general reasons. The escape code can be interpreted multiple ways, at least by its intended recipient if not by other software that could intercept it. For example, Tmux needs a sensibly tuned "escape-time" parameter to distinguish between the key press and escape sequences used for color, etc. [More info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Invalid_and_ambiguous_sequences_in_use) - maybe you requested color, maybe you sent `alt+[`. anything's possible. Nesting escapes might resolve the ambiguity, in the style of `printf`'s '%q', but it depends.

Comment: Your last comment is definitely a clue - Zsh applied substitution, which should have been the end of the story, but an additional substitution step occurred, which bypasses protections like the '%q' I mentioned. The next step is to determine if this substitution is implicit in the prompt construction (in which case you can just defer evaluation with an extra wrapper) or if it's an anomaly you can isolate (try non-Python, another shell, another term emu, and so on.) I know this is an old question, but the problem itself isn't going anywhere.